# Efficiently remove the last word from a string in Swift

Tags: swift, string

I am trying to build an autocorrect system, so I need to be able to delete the last word typed and replace it with the correct one. My solution:

```
func autocorrect() {
    hasWordReadyToCorrect = false
    var wordProxy = self.textDocumentProxy as UITextDocumentProxy
    var stringOfWords = wordProxy.documentContextBeforeInput

    fullString = "Unset Value"

    if stringOfWords != nil {
        var words = stringOfWords.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())
        for word in words {
            arrayOfWords += [word]
        }
        println("The last word of the array is \(arrayOfWords.last)")
        for (mistake, word) in autocorrectList {
            println("The mistake is \(mistake)")
            if mistake == arrayOfWords.last {
                fullString = word
                hasWordReadyToCorrect = true
            }
        }
        println("The corrected String is \(fullString)")

    }
}
```

This method is called after each keystroke, and if the space is pressed, it corrects the word. My problem comes in when the string of text becomes longer than about 20 words. It takes a while for it to fill the array each time a character is pressed, and it starts to lag to a point of not being able to use it. Is there a more efficient and elegant Swift way of writing this function? I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1.**

One thing, iteration isn't necessary for this:

```
for word in words {
    arrayOfWords += [word]
}
```

You can just do:

```
arrayOfWords += words
```

**2.**

Breaking the for loop will prevent iterating unnecessarily:

```
for (mistake, word) in autocorrectList {
    println("The mistake is \(mistake)")
    if mistake == arrayOfWords.last {
        fullString = word
        hasWordReadyToCorrect = true
        break; // Add this to stop iterating through 'autocorrectList'
    }
}
```

Or even better, forget the for-loop completely:

```
if let word = autocorrectList[arrayOfWords.last] {
    fullString = word
    hasWordReadyToCorrect = true
}
```

Ultimately what you're doing is seeing if the last word of the entered text matches any of the keys in the autocorrect list.  You can just try to get the value directly using optional binding like this.

**---**

I'll let you know if I think of more.

Comment: Dang! You simplified all my code into 3 lines, and it works SO much better! I'll keep the page open in case you do think of more, but as of now I have no problem with lag in a large paragraph that I typed. The only thing I'm worried about though, my dictionary that it checks from is only about 10 words long because it was a test before I made the full list. Do you think this code will remain as efficient when the list of words gets much much longer?

Comment: @SomeGuy - Dictionaries are designed to be optimized, so the lookup shouldn't inhibit performance too much.  With that being said, having an extremely large dictionary and processing with each key stroke might show some performance hit.  I can't find any good swift benchmarks from searching around so I can't really say for sure.

Comment: Is there a more efficient way you can think of to make an autocorrect system? I've just been making key value pairs for things like theee being the key and there being the value, so if the user types theee, it changes to there.

Comment: Great question! I haven't spent enough time delving into the problem to make a good suggestion. Your approach seems logical enough, perhaps using predicates to search for "like" words would yield more results, but would be much slower. It might be something where you simply have an array of valid words and an algorithm that determines how close of a match they are, then recommend that match if it's over a certain percentage of 'closeness'. A lot of people get paid a lot of money to work on this problem. I'd stick with what works first then iterate and develop it more in the future! Good luck!

Answer (score 24):

This doesn't answer the OP's "autocorrect" issue directly, but this is code is probably the easiest way to answer the **question posed in the title**:

Swift 3

```
let myString = "The dog jumped over a fence"
let myStringWithoutLastWord = myString.components(separatedBy: " ").dropLast().joined(separator: " ")
```